# Junit 4 Testing coverage

Tags: java, testing, junit, code-coverage, junit4

I am unable to cover next method:

```
protected void dealDamage(int damage, String damageType) {
    this.setDamageDealt(damage);
    this.setDamageDealtType(damageType);
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
@Test
@Parameters({"30, physical"})
public void dealDamage(int damage, String damageType) throws Exception {
    this.creature.setDamageDealt(damage);
    this.creature.setDamageDealtType(damageType);
    assertEquals(this.creature.getDamageDealt(), 30);
    assertEquals(this.creature.getDamageDealtType(), "physical");
}
```

Test return success, but method is not covered at all. Where could be my mistake? Do I miss something?

Comment: You will need to look at what is actually calling that method, and when you want us to answer, maybe even post that.

Comment: If you want to cover `dealDamage`... Why aren't you invoking `dealDamage`???

Comment: I didn't use `@Parameters` from junit, but shouldn't you be calling the method that you want to test? I don't see where you call `dealDamage`

Comment: @Pelocho How to invoke it and what will I achieve from it?

Comment: @sfat please add this as an answer

Comment: @TeodorKolev added answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are not calling the method that you want to unit test, i.e. `dealDamage()`